# How to install the NVidia driver on a notebook?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have used Ubuntu and Debian on my desktop for a long time. There I don't have an onboard graphic card but I'm on a notebook now and I have an 'Intel HD Graphics 4600' on my motherboard. My Ubuntu isn't recognizing my nVidia GT 740M and I can't use 'additional drivers' to install anything.

How can I get my graphic card to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, if you run the following command, what are the results?

lspci | grep -i vga

Does it list an Nvidia card as installed?

It may be that you have no Nvidia card at all. If you do, in fact, have an Nvidia card installed, it may be disabled by your hardware configuration options in EFI/BIOS.

(for example, I have a ThinkPad W530 with both Intel and Nvidia cards in it. You can specify one or the other, or both where it dynamically switches between the two)

If you do have an Nvidia card, and the "Additional Drivers" section isn't listing it... it may be an unsupported model.

If you will report back your findings, I'll do what I can to help you. :)